# Alternatives to LDA for big datasets

Tags: r, classification, projection

I'm analyzing a big dataset of gene expression in R, with 100 samples and 50.000 genes.

I already made some very informative PCA projections of inter-sample patterns. Now I want to make some projections of the data maximizing the differences between the labels I have for the samples.

Normally I would do this with the `lda()` function from the `MASS` package. However, this is way too slow and memory intensive.

If the goal is to produce a projection of the samples maximizing the difference between known labels, what are some good alternatives to `lda()`?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many methods to choose from, like [support vector machines](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf), [elastic net](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html), or [nearest shrunken centroids](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pamr/index.html). Try them out and return if you get stuck, or have a look at the sister site [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). If you are looking for a broad introduction I recommend getting a copy of [Elemnets of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not so much interested in the classification itself, but rather the projection of the point into 2 dimensions for plotting.

Comment: Perhaps [partial least squares](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v18/i02/paper) is the way to go then? That is if you are looking for an alternative to PCA that designs components specifically for separating your classes.

Comment: Your answer led me on the correct path, as far as I can tell partial least squares discrimant analysis (PLSDA) is a nice alternative to LDA to generate a low dimensional representation of the data. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Summary of our discussion in the comments to the question

Linear discriminant analysis does not work on data sets with more features than observations, so you need some form of regularization. If you want to do classification but are mainly interested in the predictive patterns, rather than the predictions themselves, you can use partial least squares discriminant analysis (PLSDA).

However, in your case the components of PLSDA might be hard to interpret since they will contain one coefficient per gene, but it seems unrealistic to believe that all 50000 genes are relevant to the phenotype you are studying. An alternative approach I prefer is to use [nearest shrunken centroids](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pamr/index.html) or [elastic net](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) that produces sparse models (i.e. they only keep the best genes and discard those of little importance).

Answer (score 0):

You could run your LDA model on a sample of the data set.